# setState does not update array state in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I try to get value from the input and put it into object then push to new array. Then combine this array(with setState) with my state array. However, my state array value always returns empty. Could you please say where is the mistake. Thanks.

```
class AddExtraSeassion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.checkValidity = this.checkValidity.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
    this.onChangeTime = this.onChangeTime.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      checkedStudentLength: 0,
      validity: false,
      seassionDuration: null,
      seassionDate: null,
      seassionTime: null,
      showSeassion: false,
      seassions: []

    }
  }


  addSeassion = () => {
    this.setState({showSeassion: true});
  }

  onChangeDate = (event) => {
    this.setState({seassionDate: event.target.value});
  };
  onChangeTime = (event) => {
    this.setState({seassionTime: event.target.value});
  };
  onChangeDuration = (event) => {
    this.setState({seassionDuration: event.target.value});
  };

  checkValidity() {
    const seassionDate = this.state.seassionDate;
    const seassionTime = this.state.seassionTime;
    const seassionDuration = this.state.seassionDuration;

    const obj = {
      "Date": seassionDate,
      "Time": seassionTime,
      "Duration": seassionDuration
    };
    let SeassionList=[];

    SeassionList.push(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(SeassionList) + " SeassionList array"); // print result
    this.setState({
      seassions: [...this.state.seassions, SeassionList]
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.seassions) + " state array"); // always empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @norbitrial mentioned setState is async operation so console.log() will not show the updated state . If you want to check if the state is updating or not you can use the callback provided by the setState method like below:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      seassions: [...prevState.seassions, SeassionList[0]]
    }),() => {
    console.log(this.state.seassions);
})
```

Comment: yes, understand this thanks, But the problem is I want to concatenate value in created array and my state array. But what I wrote always overwrite new value to the state.

Comment: @ElchinFarhadov , I have updated the answer accordingly , Either you can get the first element from SeassionList and add it to the array or you can directly add the obj to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you should not expect to see the changes in that line of `console.log()` immediately after your usage of `setState()` because it is asynchronous action.

Also you can try using the previous state of you array and passing `obj` instead of `SeassionList`:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   seassions: [...prevState.seassions, obj]
}))
```